# How to override .phtml files in Magento 2.4

Tags: overrides, invoice, magento2.4.2, create-invoice, template-override

I want to customize the Invoice page, so I override .phtml file in:

> vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\invoice\create\items.phtml

I tried to create many files but failed:

> MyVendor\MyModule\view\adminhtml\layout\salase_invoice_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule::order/invoice/create/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> MyVendor\MyModule\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> MyVendor\MyModule\view\adminhtml\templates\order\invoice\create\items.phtml

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

So please let me know what I need to add/modify so that I can resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just change your layout file name :-

**From :-**

```
salase_invoice_custom.xml
```

**To :-**

```
sales_order_invoice_new.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!